# Retrofit 2: Async download many images and store in Android folder

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to download 20 images from remote server and store in Android folder.

Here my code:

Interface:

```
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Url String url);
```

In fragment:

```
  private void downloadImagesList(List<Image> imagesList) {
    for (Image image : imagesList) {
        final String imageSourceUrl = imageSource.getUrl();                       
            Call<ResponseBody> call = RestClientFactory.getRestClient().downloadFile(imageSourceUrl);
            call.enqueue(new DefaultRestClientCallback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Success download from url: " + imageSourceUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // code to write downloaded image to Android's local folder
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

As you can see I iterate loop and call `call.enqueue()` for every image.
Is it good solution? Is this can perform my android app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependencies like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) , [Pissaco](http://square.github.io/picasso/) etc for downloading images from remote server. Because these provide better caching and error handling. Have a look at the code below. It is using Pissaco to load the image

First add the Pissaco dependency in your `build.gradle`

> compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Comment: I edit my post. After success downloaded images I need to store every of them to local folder in Android. So I think to use Retrofit2 for download and my custom method that write to Adnroid local folder. P.S. Aslo I need to download not only images, but also PDF file.